# Master Page changes not reflected for other logged in users in sharepoint online 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-online

I have created a master page using sharepoint designer 2013. I am able to edit the page.But whenever any changes are made they are only reflected on the view of administrators site. Changes are not reflected/visible to other user who logs into the site
How to reflet the changes throughout ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "publish" and "approve" your changes. I'm not sure if Sharepoint Designer allows you to do this. You can do it in Site Settings -> Web Designer Galleries/Master pages and page layouts. Select your master page, then publish, then approve it (use corresponding toolbar options for these).

Answer (score 0):

If only you or some admin users can see the changes, then check-in, publish and approve. 
[You can do it from Designer with right-click:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5q2t.png)

If only some administrative pages show your changes, but not regular site pages, make sure the Master Page being edited is selected both as Site Master Page and System Master Page, in [Site Master Page Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJNXl.png)